# How to autofill the right textfield

Tags: swift

I need to autocomplete textfields from tableview. How can i select the right textfield(where i am writing at this moment)?
[code is here](http://prntscr.com/fghdby)

Comment: please paste the code as text and not as an image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you have two UITextFields and a UITableView and when you tap on a cell in the table view you want to put it's text into whichever text field has your input focus.

Try this:

```
if firstTextField.isFirstResponder {
    firstTextField.text = selectedCell.textLabel.text
}
if secondTextField.isFirstResponder {
    secondTextField.text = selectedCell.textLabel.text
}
```

The isFirstResponder method tells you if the control has the current focus and only one of them can.